# segmentation fault when I'm trying to print my list through my function

Tags: c++, linked-list

I know this is probably trivial to the c++ programmer, but I'm a noobie trying to figure this out. In my main, if I print my short list manually(cout << head->value etc) it works, but when I use my print function I get a segmentation fault. I've been trying to use a debugger, but I'm not very good at unix/c++ and I'm getting frustrated trying to figure this out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ListNode
{
    public:
    int value;
    ListNode* next;
};

void insertAtHead(ListNode** head, int value)
{
    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->value = value;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        *head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode;
    }
}

void printList(ListNode* head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->value << "->";
        head = head->next;
    }
}
//inserts after the node with given value
void insertAfterNode(ListNode** head,ListNode** newNode, int value)
{
    ListNode* current = *head;
    while(current != NULL && (current->value != value)) 
    {
            //cout << "Im Here";
            current = current->next;
            cout << current->value;
    }
    (*newNode)->next = current->next;
    current->next = *newNode;
}

int main()
{
    ListNode *head;
    insertAtHead(&head, 5);
    insertAtHead(&head, 10);
    ListNode* newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->value = 8;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    insertAfterNode(&head,&newNode, 5);
printList(head);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this compiles as-is. `head` is a double pointer to `ListNode`, you can barely use `operator->` to access its members.

Comment: I'm sorry i was editing my code. Let me fix it. I was initially using a local copy to print and thought maybe that was the problem, but forgot to change it back.

Comment: @user2285010 it would be good to add a constructor in `ListNode` that initializes all your member variables to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this modifications in your functions

```
void insertAtHead(ListNode** head, int value)
{
    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->value = value;

    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
}

void printList(const ListNode* head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->value << "->";
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

In `insertAtHead` you are pasing a double pointer, so comparison should be like this.

Added checking for whether `*head` is null before accessing. and if `null` adding new node as `head`

```
void insertAfterNode(ListNode** head,ListNode** newNode, int value)
{
    ListNode* current = *head;
    if (current  != NULL)
    {
       while(current != NULL && (current->value != value)) 
       {
            //cout << "Im Here";
            current = current->next;
            cout << current->value;
       }
       (*newNode)->next = current->next;
       current->next = *newNode;
    }
    else
    {
      *head = *newNode;
    }
}
```

And in main intialise `head` before use

```
int main()
{
    ListNode *head = NULL;
    insertAtHead(&head, 5);
    printList(head); // <== note: by-value, not by address or reference.
```

Comment: huzzah! Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that. Just so I know though, if I don't set head to NULL in my main is that wrong?

Comment: For what its worth, the  `if (*head == NULL)` condition in `insertAtHead()`, as well as the block containing `*head = newNode; newNode->next= NULL;` is entirely unnecessary. You can simple always set `newNode->next = *head; *head = newNode;` It would be important to check if this were a dbl-linked list, but it isn't. Also, for robustness, *both* functions should ensure the base pointer `head` is non-NULL on inception before ever dereferencing with `*head`.

Comment: @user2285010 Also, you need not pass a dbl pointer to `printList()`. The dbl pointer is only needed for functions that might change `head`, and `printList()` clearly doesn't. Eliminating that also eliminates the need for the `curr` temporary, since you can just use the single-indirection parameter as your pointer you walk through the list. I'll update the code if 555k has no problem with it, or he can himself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the next value you are trying to access is not null like this   :

```
  void printList(ListNode* head)
    {
        if (head != NULL)
        {
            while(head->next != NULL)
            {
                cout << head->value << "->";
                head = head->next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm that's not working for me. Still getting the segmentation fault. I also adjusted the parameter to use a local copy i.e. (ListNode *head)

Comment: It's possible my insertAfterNode is wrong too... it seems like I can't print if I use this function.

Comment: Yes! Don't forget to check if the ->next value is not null ! Because you try to acces to its value after current = current->next;

Answer (score 0):

Dude the first answer is correct

But i would like to make another correction

In your `while` loop in function insert after node

`current!=NULL` is incorrect because then your condition will be true if and only if the last node in the list matches the value of 5

Condition should be just `while(current->value!=value)`

by this you will reach the node having value `5`

Comment: It's current != null. Is that what you meant?

Comment: This is entirely wrong. The while-loop will never break with this logic, and quickly tap *undefined behavior* in the process, if the value being searched for is *not* in the list.

Comment: Yeah but if the value is there it will work and we can put an else condition that if value is not there then user has to input again